# no match for call when using c++0x Lambda expressions

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

This is the problematic function:

```
void Molecule::initSimilarity(int depth)
{
    int m = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < depth ; j++)
        for (int i = 0 ; i < _size ; i++)   //for any atom A
            if (!getSetMask(                //put all atoms which are equivalnt but not similar to A in their own
                                            //equivalence class
                [&](const Atom& b)->bool {return (_atoms[i]->_class == b._class) && !(isSimilar(*_atoms[i],b));},
                [&m](Atom& b){b._class = m;}     //113
                ).none()) m++;                   //114
}
```

And the output:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.5/memory:82:0,
>
> ```
>              from /usr/include/boost/dynamic_bitset_fwd.hpp:15,
>              from /usr/include/boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp:36,
>              from /usr/include/boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp:15,
>              from DataStructures/Molecule.h:21,
>              from DataStructures/Molecule.cpp:8:
> ```
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.5/functional: In
>   static member function ‘static void
>   std::_Function_handler::_M_invoke(const
>   std::_Any_data&, _ArgTypes ...) [with
>   _Functor = Molecule::initSimilarity(int)::,
>   _ArgTypes = {Atom}]’:
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.5/functional:2103:6:
>   instantiated from
>   ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes
>   ...)>::function(_Functor, typename
>   std::enable_if<(!
>   std::is_integral<_Functor>::value),
>   std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes
>   ...)>::_Useless>::type) [with _Functor
>   = Molecule::initSimilarity(int)::,
>   _Res = void, _ArgTypes = {Atom}, typename std::enable_if<(!
>   std::is_integral<_Functor>::value),
>   std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes
>   ...)>::_Useless>::type =
>   std::function::_Useless]’
>
> DataStructures/Molecule.cpp:114:5:
>   instantiated from here
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.5/functional:1713:9:
>   error: no match for call to
>
> ‘(Molecule::initSimilarity(int)::)
>   (Atom)’
>
> DataStructures/Molecule.cpp:113:17:
>   note: candidate is:
>   Molecule::initSimilarity(int)::

I have no idea how this happens and what exactly that means, and I couldn't find any help on Google either...

The called function (isSimilar()):

```
bool Molecule::isSimilar(const Atom &A, const Atom &B)
    {
        AtomSet S;
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        {
            if (!_adjecancy[A._index][i]) continue; //Skip any atoms which aren't adjecant to A
            int K = findAtom([&](const Atom& b){return (_adjecancy[B._index][b._index]) && (B._class == b._class) && (!S[B._index]);});
            if (K == -1) return false;
            S.flip(K);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and the one called from it:

```
int Molecule::findAtom(std::function<bool (const Atom)> property, std::function<void (Atom)> action = NULL)
{
    for (int i=0 ; i<_size ; i++)
    {
        if (property(*_atoms[i]))
        {
            if (action != NULL) action(*_atoms[i]);
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

used typedefs:

```
typedef dynamic_bitset<> AtomSet;
typedef dynamic_bitset<>::size_type atom_ind;
```

and of course, the function which stars in the error output:

```
AtomSet Molecule::getSetMask(std::function<bool (const Atom)> property, std::function<void (Atom)> action = NULL)
{
    dynamic_bitset<> ret(_size);
    if (property != NULL) for(int i=0; i<_size ; i++) ret.set(i, property(*_atoms[i]));
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to show the complete signature for the function you're calling, including any typedefs it depends on.

Comment: Hi, I've added anything I think might be relevant, thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `getSetMask`, I should have said that the first time.

Comment: Doh, added about everything _but_ the function referred to in the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see references in the argument type of the lambda, and no references in the functor types needed by `getSetMask`.

Does your error persist if you make those consistent?

i.e. if you want action to modify the `Atom`, you need

```
std::function<void (Atom&)> action
```

Comment: That seemed to work, thanks a bundle! Any chance you could elaborate on the error source a little bit, or refer me to some readable materia? As this functionality is rather new reading material is sparse. Thanks!

Comment: @Shai: lambdas may be new in C++0x, but the error message isn't.  "error: no match for call" means "parameter type mismatch" (or "wrong number of parameters"), you'd have gotten the same message even if you wrote your own functor, I believe.  The context part of the error message is messier, of course, since the functor has no name, but the troubleshooting approach is unchanged.